# PHP tag in Image url?

Tags: php, wordpress

Pretty basic problem, so sorry but have been banging my head off the wall for well over an hour.

basically writing a script to set a default Wordpress featured image for a category if there is no featured set.

```
            if ( get_the_post_thumbnail( $projects->post->ID ) ) { 
                $imagetag = get_the_post_thumbnail( $projects->post->ID, 'portfolio-thumb', array( 'class' => 'img-square', 'alt' => get_the_title($projects->post->ID) ) ).''; }
            else {

            $imagetag .='<img src="ThisIsMySite\img\"'.$tag->slug .'"image.jpg" />';                
            }
```

All works, except I can't get the else image to work, the closest I can get is to output :

img src="ThisIsMySite\img\"maths"image.jpg"

(Where maths is the current category)
It must be something stupid / really obvious I'm missing / doing wrong but I can't work it out.

Comment: um you have to many `"` use this `'<img src="ThisIsMySite\img\'.$tag->slug .'image.jpg" />'`

Comment: You're concatenating inside your else statement with `.=`, shouldn't it just be `=` without the period?

Comment: @AndyWarren that *may* be valid but impossible to say without seeing more of the code.

Comment: They'd have had had to set the `$imagetag` variable outside the conditional, but if that is the case then the if value would also need to be concatenatred. Right?

Comment: If `$imagetag` doesn't exist then the `.=` will create it by concatenating the string onto a `null` value.

Comment: Thanks for your replies, although there " ' were out of alignment in that particular example, believe me I tried every combination imaginable and by the time I posted this I think I was just going blind to them 'cause if it didn't give me an unexpected result then the whole page would just go blank.  The actual fix was that the \ were the wrong way around, should have been / ... just in case anyone else has a similar problem (but yeah, the quotes were out of alignment too :) ).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Clearshot66](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45848752/3536236) almost had the right idea, but had flipped the quotes. You want to retain the single quotes and remove the excess double quotes.

single quotes here are PHP quotes, double quotes are HTML entity quotes.

```
   $imagetag .='<img src="ThisIsMySite/img/'.$tag->slug .'image.jpg" />';
```

aka:

```
 $imagetag = '<string 
                      HTML ELEMENT = 
                      "HTML URL STING>' 
             CONCAT $tag->slug CONCAT 
             '< HTML ELEMENT "
              string>';
```

***Also*** replace your `\` with `/` because it's online, it uses forward slashes as seperators rather than backward slashes.

Comment: Beat me to it. I'd just like to add that if you **don't** change the slashes, you'll need to escape the backslash before the closing quotation mark, otherwise that slash will actually escape the quote instead of ending the string: `src="ThisIsMySite\img\\'.$tag->slug`

Comment: It was actually the slashes causing the problems,  so some of the other suggestions probably did work too ... just changing the slashes stopped me getting a blank screen.
Thanks so much.

Comment: I was out of it yesterday afternoon my fault!

Answer (score 0):

this should do it for you

```
$imagetag .='<img src="ThisIsMySite/img/'.$tag->slug .'image.jpg" />';
```

hope this helps